# Bitlocker or SecretZone?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I want to encrypt an external hard drive (and only the external hard drive). What are the advantages/disadvantages of Samsung SecretZone vs bitlocker (I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise).

One issue I've found so far, bitlocker needs TPM installed and I do not presently have that installed. Is this additional overhead for my system or configuration? Especially as I'm not concerned about encrypting the fixed drives in my computer.

**Update:**
I am asking what are the very specific feature differences between the two solutions for the very specific case of only encrypting an external drive. I'm not asking for opinion as to which someone likes better.

And yes, like a large number of questions on this site, in a couple of years the answer will be obsolete. It's still a useful question today.

For both products, the latest version.

Comment: We do not do product recomendations here at Superuser. TPM is handled by hardware any overhead wouldn't be detectable. Even if we did do product recomendations you didn't even indicate what is and is not important to you.  On a personal note, I suppose you have to decided, who you trust more Samsung or Microsoft when it comes to your security.

Comment: @Ramhound Strictly speaking, this isn't really a "product recommendation" question. It's asking for "product comparison", which is a fairly objective process if all we're doing is looking at the technical capabilities. However, it is still worth stating that it's a fairly broad topic without specific version details (Bitlocker is semi-implied with the specification of Windows 7 Enterprise, but no version for SecretZone is declared). Any answers would also become irrelevant or outdated after just a few years, when users have likely moved on to newer OSs and updated products.

Comment: FYI: BitLocker *does not* require TPM. It's mandatory by default, but that option can be changed. Google a bit and you'll find it - quite possibly on this site, for that matter.

Comment: @Iszi - Alright. The current question is overally broad and any answers would be primarily opinion-based answers for that reason. The author indicates he does not even use TPM, and unless he is willing [work around that requirement](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/) he likely should look at other solutions other then Bitlocker.  In other words the question still seems not to be on topic, or at the very least, the question's scope can be reduced.

Comment: @iszi It looks like no TPM bitlocker requires a USB stick with the encryption keys. Understandable but overkill for my need. I think the SecretZone approach is the less hassle choice. FWIW, I wish someone would come up with a decent encryption system that was basically invisible and worked from your Windows login.

Comment: Bitlocker without TPM does not require a USB stick, except to store a recovery key if you don't want it uploaded to your Microsoft account. For whole-disk encryption it would be impractical, if not impossible, to create something that is completely transparent and uses your Windows login - especially for domain-based systems where the login credentials may be changed on another computer. This would essentially require the bootloader to be able to read your system drive and/or communicate with your domain controller before you've authenticated yourself.

Comment: @Iszi Windows has local encrypted storage on each system where the data in that is available once a user has logged in. What if the credentials were stored there? I would have to enter the credentials once on each computer I accessed it form. But only once. Wouldn't that work? (And yes, now I've gone from what can be done today to what could be implemented.)

Comment: @DavidThielen No, that would not work because Windows itself would still be inaccessible during the part of the booting phase which requires access to the credential store. When you're putting a password into a whole-disk encryption bootloader, the password isn't being checked against OS-level credentials - it's being used as part of a key to unlock the decryption key necessary to read the rest of the drive. If you're interested in further exploring the topic, I suggest asking a question over on [security.se].